# Merging two binary trees

Tags: java, merge, tree, binary, binary-tree

I want to merge a tree with another tree, t. If there is overlapping data, I want to add them together. This is my code right now. I don't understand how to do this merge function with only parameter t. Doesn't merge usually have two parameters?

```
public class TreeFunctions {

   private TreeNode root;

   public TreeFunctions(TreeNode root) {
        this.root = root;
   }

   public TreeNode merge(TreeNode t) {
        TreeNode curr = this.root;
        if (curr == null) {
            return t;
        }

        if (t == null) {
            return curr;
        }

        curr.data += t.data;
        curr.left = merge(t.left);
        curr.right = merge(t.right);
        return curr;
   }
}

public class TreeNode{
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    int data;

    public TreeNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public TreeNode(int data, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public static String inOrder(TreeNode a) {
        if(a == null) return "";
        else return inOrder(a.left).trim() + " " + a.data + " " + inOrder(a.right).trim();
    }
}
```

EDIT
My tests for merge:

```
public void testMerge2() {
        TreeFunctions c = new TreeFunctions(new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(2), null));
        TreeNode d = new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(1));
        TreeNode res2 = c.merge(d);
        assertEquals(TreeNode.inOrder(res2).trim(), "4 7 1");
    }

public void testMerge3() {
        TreeFunctions c = new TreeFunctions(new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(2), null));
        TreeNode res2 = c.merge(null);
        assertEquals(TreeNode.inOrder(res2).trim(), "2 5");
    }

public void testMerge4() {
        TreeFunctions c = new TreeFunctions(new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(5), null), null));
        TreeNode res2 = c.merge(new TreeNode(1, null, new TreeNode(2, null, new TreeNode(5))));
        assertEquals(TreeNode.inOrder(res2).trim(), "5 2 2 2 5");
    }
```

Comment: Well this code you've found, calls the method from a Node object (1) and target Node object (2) is given as parameter. It's like this :  node1.merge(node2); node1 and node2 are the two inputs you're talking about. Since merge is a recursive function, It goes all the way down from the target node object(2) but it stays on caller node object (1) so It collects/merges all the data onto caller node object's data all the way down to the bottom of tree path starting from target node object (2). Be sure that this is what you want.

Comment: @AntiqTech Yes, that is what I want. If i have two trees, a and b, I want b's data to be copied to a's data when a.merge(b) is called. However, for some reason my code is not working and I get a ```StackOverflowError```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace for the StackOverflowError?

Comment: @ashpcj24 there might be some problem with left/right linkage. recursive is called untill it reaches an end node. Also a correction for what I said before: Data is collected on caller's root.data => this.root.data .  I don't get this part. this.root is the parent of the caller node or root of the tree? anyhow.  If you're getting stackoverflow then you're missing the stopping conditions => 1: this.root is null 2: given target node is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my answer per your responses. I believe this is what you want.Please try it and let me know.

In the code, function goes down one level for both t1 and t2 so that merge always takes place on the same level and the same side (left-left/right-right).

```
 public TreeNode merge(TreeNode t) {
        TreeNode curr = this.root; 
        merge2(curr,t);
        return curr;
   }
   public  void merge2(TreeNode t1,TreeNode t2) {
        if(t2==null)
            return;
        t1.data += t2.data;
        if(t2.left!=null)
        {
            if(t1.left==null)
                t1.left = new TreeNode(0);
            merge2(t1.left,t2.left);
        }
        if(t2.right!=null)
        {
            if(t1.right==null)
                t1.right = new TreeNode(0);
            merge2(t1.right,t2.right);
        }

   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't i want to return ```curr``` (the current tree) if ```t``` (the new tree) is null, because it would have no data to copy over? However, changing ```curr``` to ```null`` seemed to work for that specific test, but I still get a StackOverflowError for the tests that I just added to my post.

Comment: You already have the root node where merge is first called. That one is returned after all the recursive calls ended. When you try to return curr when the parameter is null is creating an infinite loop because of the lines : " curr.left = merge(t.left);" and " curr.right = merge(t.right);" from the second level of recursive calls on. So the recursive calls just do not end. I'm looking at the new code just now. I will add comment when I have a solution.

Comment: You always return "curr" from merge() and "curr" is always the same object. So inevitably you perform the assignment : curr.left = curr , curr.right = curr. I've missed this on the first time around. So as long as you return curr from the merge, it will enter infinite loop. Current algorithm doe snot produce what you want. You want level-by-level node-to-node (obj1.leftnode merges obj2.leftnode  obj1.rightnode merge obj2.rightnode etc) from what I understand of the example test results.

Comment: How would I correct that? I thought that's what curr.left = merge(t.left); and curr.right = merge(t.right); do.

Comment: I've modified the answer. Please take a look at this answer try it and let me know the result.